# Seperate Input/Output type for a Table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, substitution

I was wondering if it is possible to have the input for a column be one string, with the output being a different string through some dictionary in PostgreSQL. I do know how to use CASE to convert numbers to strings using a SELECT statement, however, I was hoping to create a table such that inputs only require numbers but outputs always give strings.

As an example, for currency USD, CDN and GBP, where 1 = USD, 2 = CDN and 3 = GBP, an example would be:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (

currency CHAR (1) CHECK (currency IN ('1','2','3'))
)
```

Where I could do this:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (currency)
VALUES ('1') 

INSERT INTO test_table (currency)
VALUES ('1')  

INSERT INTO test_table (currency)
VALUES ('2')  

INSERT INTO test_table (currency)
VALUES ('3')  

INSERT INTO test_table (currency)
VALUES ('3')
```

and the output would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Create a currency table and join to it when you query.

Comment: FYI, your title/description does not match your example. You are asking for `numeric` input and `char` output, but showing a `char` input field and values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE expression:

```
select case currency
         when '1' then 'USD'
         when '2' then 'CDN'
         when '3' then 'GBP'
         when '4' then 'EUR'
       end as currency
from test_table;
```

---

But a better solution would be to create a currency table:

```
create table currency
(
   id integer primary key,
   currency_code varchar(3)
);
```

Then create a foreign key from your base table to the lookup table:

```
create table test_table
(
  ...
  currency_id integer not null references currency,
  ...
);
```

Then use a join to display the code:

```
select c.code
from test_table t
  join currency c on c.id = t.currency_id;
```